# flutter problem I can't load my application on the emulator

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

HOPE YOU GO VERY WELL

I'm new with flutter programming , i just start a new project
the problem is when i want to RUN it when the emulator is already running
nothing happens and i can't get the output of the code

[output of the run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ndm.png) in fact it stacks here and nothing happen of the emulator

NEED SOME HELP PLEASE

Comment: Seems it is downloading sdk, you can be sure opening `task manager networkTab`. Just need to wait, I believe.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes i waited until the sdk was downloaded , but nothing changes !!

Comment: what is your TaskManager network status on dart or BTIS

Comment: Thanks Yeasin i just solved the problem by installing another emulator

Answer (score 0):

[flutter doctor ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUZSf.png)
That's the ouptut of $flutter doctor

i'm running the app on android studio

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot, there seems to be a compile error. Check the Dart analysis tab and see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you use android studio try to this :

- search (with double shift) `avd manager`
- click more arrow on your emulator
- click on `wipe data`
  [image]

and in `File > Inavalidate Caches / Restart`